# Flex IconItemRenderer change color on selected

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile, iconitemrenderer

So what i want to do is to change the style of an iconitemrenderer when the item is selected. i have tried checking the state of my item but it does not seem to worki.

```
<s:IconItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  creationComplete="onStart()" stateChangeComplete="stateChangedHandler()"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  labelField="name"  decorator="/assets/highres/customerArrow.png" iconFunction="getIcon" iconWidth="60" iconHeight="60" iconField="icon" labelFunction="getName" >
```

stateChangedHandler() has a trace in it which is never triggered. My final goal is to change the label from black color on normal state to white color on selected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
<s:IconItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  creationComplete="onStart()" stateChangeComplete="stateChangedHandler()"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  labelField="name"  decorator="/assets/highres/customerArrow.png" iconFunction="getIcon" iconWidth="60" iconHeight="60" iconField="icon" color.normal="0x000000" color.selected="0xffffff" labelFunction="getName">
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="selected" />
    </s:states>
</s:IconItemRenderer>
```

Comment: hi Crabar, thanks for your answer. unfortunately i already have tried this one and it does not work. it looks like the event for changing the state does not work. I am using flex 4.13 and im not sure if this is a bug or there is a different implementation method.